# There is 'No' data in generated .csv file from Gatling

Tags: java, scala, csv, gatling

I am able to generate **csv file** from below code but there is no data in it (it has data cross-checked with sqlYog with same query). It only prints "Asset Ids" in one column and throws ClassCastException. Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks.

[image]

Here is my script.

```
import java.io._
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class generateCsv extends Simulation {

    val username = System.getProperty("username", "user1")
    val password = System.getProperty("password", "user1")
    val testUrl = System.getProperty("testUrl", "https://someurl.net")

    val csvFileLocation = "D:/myDir/myfile.csv"
    val dbQuery = jdbcFeeder("jdbc:mysql://10.10.40.10:3306/master", "admin", "admin", "SELECT ID_ assetID FROM TableName")

    var recordCount = dbQuery.records.length

    val out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(csvFileLocation))
    val writer = new CSVWriter(out)
    var Ids = new Array[String](recordCount)

    Ids(0) = "Asset Ids"

    var i = 1

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL(testUrl)
        .inferHtmlResources()
        .acceptHeader("""*/*""")
        .basicAuth(username, password)
        .acceptEncodingHeader("""gzip, deflate""")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("""en-US,en;q=0.8""")
        .connection("""keep-alive""")
        .userAgentHeader("""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36""")

    val scn = scenario("Database Query")
    .repeat (recordCount) {
        feed(dbQuery)
        .exec { session =>
                Ids(i)  = session("assetID").as[String]
                        i = i + 1
                        session
            }
    }
    after{
                writer.writeNext(Ids)
                writer.close()
            }

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

**Error:**

```
84057 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] ERROR i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anonfun$build$1$$anon$1 - 'sessionHook-2' crashed on session Session(Database Query,8451783577631963111-0,Map(b1075cf5-e3c8-47d6-96bd-ff74284b4e7c -> 4, timestamp.b1075cf5-e3c8-47d6-96bd-ff74284b4e7c -> 1488276658897, assetID -> 6),1488276658892,0,KO,List(ExitOnCompleteLoopBlock(b1075cf5-e3c8-47d6-96bd-ff74284b4e7c)),<function1>), forwarding to the next one
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.abc.gatling.generateCsv$$anonfun$2.apply(generateCsv.scala:57) ~[na:na]
    at com.abc.gatling.generateCsv$$anonfun$2.apply(generateCsv.scala:56) ~[na:na]
    at io.gatling.core.action.SessionHook.executeOrFail(SessionHook.scala:35) ~[gatling-core-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at io.gatling.core.action.Failable$class.execute(Actions.scala:71) ~[gatling-core-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at io.gatling.core.action.SessionHook.execute(SessionHook.scala:28) ~[gatling-core-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at io.gatling.core.action.Action$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Actions.scala:29) ~[gatling-core-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.12.jar:na]
    at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.aroundReceive(BaseActor.scala:22) ~[gatling-core-2.1.7.jar:2.1.7]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.12.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.12.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.12.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.12.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.12.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
84072 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] INFO  i.g.core.controller.Controller - End user #8451783577631963111-0
84179 [main] INFO  i.g.c.result.reader.FileDataReader - Collected List(D:\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.1.7\results\generateCsv-1488276658757\simulation.log) from generateCsv-1488276658757
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in the stacktrace shows where the error is happening: Line 57 in generateCsv.scala. Since your code example doesn't have line numbers and is shorter than 57 lines, I assume this is the line

```
Ids(i)  = session("assetID").as[String]
```

where you try to case a the assetID to String, but which is a value of type Long according to the error message. You could use the toString method to transform the Long into a String:

```
Ids(i)  = session("assetID").as[Long].toString
```

Comment: Yes that line number is correct one. I have replaced .as[String] to .toString.
in output i get this for all the lines:


SessionAttribute(Session(Database Query,949002059540811697-0,Map(4a27dcfa-986d-41c6-81b9-c965ff0f6c40 -> 0, timestamp.4a27dcfa-986d-41c6-81b9-c965ff0f6c40 -> 1488284879536, assetID -> -1),1488284879532,0,OK,List(ExitOnCompleteLoopBlock(4a27dcfa-986d-41c6-81b9-c965ff0f6c40)),<function1>),assetID)

Comment: could you try Ids(i)  = session("assetID").as[Long].toString

Comment: Thanks a lot Harald. That worked. Please edit your answer. will accept it. 
in excel file data prints in Row, do you know how do I change it to column?

Comment: Thanks, you can use writeAll instead of writeNext

Comment: Tried but Error says,
type mismatch;
found   : Array[String]
required: java.util.List[Array[String]]
writer.writeAll(Ids)

Comment: Sorry, Data prints in Column (Horizontally). I need to print data in rows (vertically)

Comment: You can convert to the Ids to the right java type for the writeAll method as follows:  
`import collection.JavaConverters._`  and then replace the writeNext call with
    
`writer.writeAll(Ids.iterator.toBuffer[String].map(s => Array(s)).asJava)`